# Setting the opacity (maybe using 'background' property) when form is selected

Tags: css

I want an overlay of the whole screen except the form so people can focus on it.

This solution would be ideal, but the form won't change back.

```
body {
  opacity: .4
}

.form:focus {
  opacity: 1 /* crap, doesn't work */
}
```

This doesn't really work

```
some-element {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code please :) ?

Comment: i guess you ignored `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit of javascript to select and interact with the parent of your `inputs`, as well as the overlay. You can toggle ***active*** class so you can manage your CSS with actual CSS, which I find cleaner.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('#overlay');

  $('input').focusin(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    overlay.addClass('active');
  });

  $('input').focusout(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    overlay.removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

form.active {
  z-index: 100;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#overlay.active {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </form>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```